# Why `__device__` function has CPU assembly generated?

Tags: cuda

In CUDA source code, why does a `__device__` function have CPU asm generated for it?

Link to the code example:
https://godbolt.org/z/hWPof71Kj

Comment: A guess -- to allow taking address from a `__host__ __device__` function in a common path (and not using it for anything in a host path). But strictly speaking even taking it is illegal.

Comment: Looking at the generated code, it appears to just call `exit(1)` (aka terminate the process and return an error).  Presumably this is a stub to handle the case where something goes wrong and host code gets called instead of device code.